# Pauli-Villars regularization and self-energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, propagator, regularization, self-energy

In the calculation of the electron self-energy in QED (one-loop level), there is a UV and IR divergent integral that needs to be regularized. A common choice for the regularization is the Pauli-Villars regularization (PVR):
$$\frac{1}{k^2+i\varepsilon}\longrightarrow\frac{1}{k^2-\mu^2+i\varepsilon}-\frac{1}{k^2-\Lambda^2+i\varepsilon}\tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\mu$ is a fictitious mass to regulate the IR divergence and $\Lambda$ a cutoff scale.

Actually the IR regulation is a separate issue, so I'll consider it as such and put $\mu$ there before performing (PVR).
$$\frac{1}{k^2-\mu^2+i\varepsilon}\longrightarrow\frac{1}{k^2-\mu^2+i\varepsilon}-\frac{1}{k^2-\Lambda^2+i\varepsilon}\tag{1a}\label{1a}$$
In the case I'm working with a couple of changes of variables have been made, in such a way that the remaining propagator is of the form
$$\frac{1}{q^2-\Delta(\mu)+i\varepsilon}$$
and the substitution corresponding to \eqref{1} would be
$$\frac{1}{q^2-\Delta(\mu)+i\varepsilon}\longrightarrow \frac{1}{q^2-\Delta(\mu)+i\varepsilon}-\frac{1}{q^2-\Delta(\Lambda)+i\varepsilon}\tag{2}\label{2}$$

The problem is that in the integral I have a *squared* propagator $\frac{1}{[q^2-\Delta(\mu)+i\varepsilon]^2}$, which according to \eqref{1a} should be replaced by
$$\left\{\frac{1}{q^2-\Delta(\mu)+i\varepsilon}-\frac{1}{q^2-\Delta(\mu)+i\varepsilon}\right\}^2$$
but the replacement that is made is
$$\frac{1}{[q^2-\Delta(\mu)+i\varepsilon]^2}-\frac{1}{[q^2-\Delta(\Lambda)+i\varepsilon]^2}$$
which is clearly different and amounts to
$$\frac{1}{[k^2-\mu^2+i\varepsilon]^2}\longrightarrow\frac{1}{[k^2-\mu^2+i\varepsilon]^2}-\frac{1}{[k^2-\Lambda^2+i\varepsilon]^2}\tag{3}\label{3}$$

Can we still consider this as PVR? Why do they call in PVR and then do something different? My guess is that they *do* use PVR but only keep the highest order $\Lambda$ terms (as the difference in the two resulting expressions would only be a lower $\Lambda$ order).
Considering that

- the high $\lambda$ limit is usually taken at the very end,
- every computation I've seen is akin to \eqref{2},

I'm now led to believe that \eqref{1a} is really a shorthand for \eqref{2}

### Sources

I do not have an exact source to provide as I'm relying on a set of notes of mine. The comment section of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/229598/259324) answer are related to this issue, although they don't satisfy my doubts.

- P&S apparently do something similar in Chapter 7, pag. 218 of the 1995 edition.
- Bjorken&Drell in Relativistic Quantum Mechanics, page 154 introduce a generalized version of PVR, using more summands. In that case they define the procedure in a manner more akin to \eqref{2}, see eq. $(8.11)$ thereof.